# Drupal: "Error: Class not found" when calling a function from a controller within submitForm()

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to do some stuff while submitting a form in a custom module. Some of that is done by calling a function from a controller. That's when i get:

`Error: Class 'Drupal\ice_cream\Controller\OrderController' not found in Drupal\ice_cream\Form\OrderForm->submitForm() (line 77 of modules\custom\ice_cream\src\Form\OrderForm.php).`

**As far as I can tell the namespaces aren't wrong? Or is that not related to this error?**

This is how my OrderForm.php and submitForm() looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ice_cream\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\ice_cream\Controller\OrderController;

/**
 * Implements the order form.
 */
class OrderForm extends FormBase {

... (omitted code for getFormid and buildForm)

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        //Check if the order is ice or waffles.   
        if($form_state->getValue('foodType') == 'ice'){
          //Save order to the DB.
          OrderController::saveOrder($form_state->getValue('foodType'), $form_state->getValue('taste'));

          ... (more code)
        }

    }
}
```

This is how the controller looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ice_cream\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

/**
 * Order controller for interacting (insert, select,...) with the ice cream table in the DB.
 */
class OrderController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Saves an order for either Ice or Waffles with their options (tast or toppings).
   */
  public function saveOrder($foodType, $options) {

    $connection = Database::getConnection();

    //Check if ice or waffles (to only insert the right field with $options).
    if($foodType == "ice"){
        $result = $connection->insert('ice_cream')
        ->fields([
            'foodType' => $foodType,
            'taste' => $options,
            'toppings' => "",
        ])
        ->execute();
        return true;

    }elseif($foodType == "waffles"){
        $result = $connection->insert('ice_cream')
        ->fields([
            'foodType' => $foodType,
            'taste' => "",
            'toppings' => $options,
        ])
        ->execute();
        return true;

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Just solved it with my mentor. The code was more or less correct, still needed to make my functions static in the OrderController and also I made a stupid error of forgetting the .php extension in my filename when I created it with the 'touch' terminal command...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
$obj= new OrderController;
$obj->saveOrder($form_state->getValue('foodType'), $form_state->getValue('taste'));
```

Comment: Just solved it with my mentor. The code was more or less correct, still needed to make my functions static in the OrderController and also I made a stupid error of forgetting the .php extension in my filename when I created it with the 'touch' terminal command...